# Trouble with reading a string from a keyboard scanner in java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBJjR.png)The point is to get the users input but only by the string values like CA so I can print out california, but the problem is

*if (name == "AL")* when the program runs and I input "AL"
the console does not print "The state is Alabama" but instead terminates the program. So how do I resolve converting this?
Thanks

Comment: Can you share your code

Comment: You are doing string comparison using == instead use .equals